# Error Trapping Strings and Integers

Tags: python

I am trying to create an error trap using a try-except catch to prevent the user from entering a string, however when I run the code, it does not catch the error.

```
info=False
count=input("How many orders would you like to place? ")
while info == False:
    try:
        count*1
        break
    except TypeError:
        print("Please enter a number next time.")
        quit()
#code continues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use a try except block

```
while True:
    try:
        count=int(input("How many orders would you like to place? "))
        break
    except:
        print("This is not a valid input. Try again\n")

print(count)
```

Comment: One comment about this code. Adding an empty `except:` without specifying the exception type will catch *every* exception including system-exit events like `KeyboardInterrupt` (thrown when you hit the `ctrl+c` key command). An improvement might be to only catch the non-system-exit exceptions by doing `except Exception:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The value that `input` returns is `string`.

you can try something like this:

```
try:
    val = int(userInput)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` times `ìnt` works perfectly in python: `'a'*3 = 'aaa'`. no exception will be raised in your  `try` block.

if you want to distiguish `int` from `str`:

```
try:
    int(count)
except ValueError:
    do_something_else()
```

note: it is `ValueError` and not `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) in the following way.

```
while True:
    try:
        count=input("How many orders would you like to place? ")
        count += 1
    except TypeError:
        print("Please enter a number next time.")
        break
```

Note that, a string can be multiplied by integer in python, so I have used addition operation since we cannot add integer to string in python.